# Google Sheets API Randomly Denying Access

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

Hello Stackoverflow users,
I am trying to pull data from a Google Sheet that I own, but without requiring the user to login to my google account.  I am using the code available [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) provided by Google.  I have inserted the appropriate Client ID, Sheet ID, and API Key. I am pulling data from two different sheets, and for several weeks, this had been working well and the data had been pulling successfully.

About 3 days ago, however, without any code changes, the sheet is now denying access randomly.  At certain times, it still works, and other times, it throws an error that reads "The caller does not have permission."  As far as I can tell, there isn't any pattern for when it works and doesn't work.

I have read many articles about this error and a few other questions already asked about this error and tried everything I could find.  I have ensured that the sheet is published to the web, ensured that none of the authentication keys or other ID's have changed,  and that it is shared to anyone on the web with view access.  Has anyone else been experiencing this issue and if so, how should one go about fixing this?

**Side Note:** I'm relatively new to working with the Google Sheets API, so if more information is needed, I'm more than willing to provide it.

Thank you.

Comment: Have the same issue, started 3 days ago.

Comment: @L105 Same here.  The problem started about 3 or 4 days ago, completely randomly.  It had been working perfectly fine before this.

Comment: I think it's a Google issue since it's working now with no reason.